# Unbranched cover of a curve of CM type

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory

Let $C$ be a curve of genus $g\geq 2$ over complex number. Assume that $C$ has complex multiplication (CM).

Does there exist such a curve $C$ such that $C'$ is also of CM type for any unbranched cover $C' \to C$?

PS:
 when $C$ is of genus one, the answer is yes. Since any unbranched cover of an elliptic curve is still an elliptic curve and is isogenous to the original one. The question now ask for the existence of such a curve of genus $g\geq 2$.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "$C$ has complex multiplication"?

Comment: @abx: $C$ has complex multiplication means the Jacobian $Jac(C)$ of $C$ has complex multiplication. The Jacobian $Jac(C)$ is an abelian variety. an abelian variety $A$ of dimension $g$ is said to have complex multiplication if the Endmorphism algebra $End_{\mathbb Q}(A)$ contains a field $K$ such that $[K:Q]=2g$ (See Mumford's <abelian variety>)

Comment: Presumably you know concretely at least one CM-type complex curve. Could you please explain how you know this one particular curve is not an example?

Comment: In otherwords, we should be clear that we know how to at least relate the jacobian of the cover to the jacobian of the base, and have an effective method for establishing non-CM-type.

Comment: @J.Martel Acturally, what you asked is very difficult to me. As far as I know, there is no systematic way to determine whether $C$ is of CM type or not.

Comment: Well with your definition of CM in the comment there is not going to exists such a $C$ because $Jac(C')$ is not going to be simple and hence $End(Jac(C')) \otimes \mathbb Q$ is not going to contain a field $K$ of degree $2g(C')$ over $\mathbb Q$. You should take as a definition of CM that $End(Jac(C')) \otimes \mathbb Q$ contains a commutative algebra of rank $2g(C')$ to make this question interesting.

Comment: P.s. do you mean: "$C'$ is also of CM type for an unbranched cover $C' \to C$." Or do you mean: "$C'$ is of CM type for all unbranched covers $C'\to C$."

Comment: @MaartenDerickx thanks, and you are right. should be commutative algebra.

Comment: @MaartenDerickx, for all unbranched covers.